# Original ID of image through thumbnail ID in Android

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

How to obtain ID of an image by the ID of the thumbnail?

And what about going from original image to thumbnail ID? Is that possible? I saw `MINI_THUMB_MAGIC` but it seems there is an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

[IMAGE_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#IMAGE_ID) of the Thumbnail record is the id of the original image.